# Making Semantic-UI vertical menu responsive

Tags: javascript, menu, semantic-ui

I am learning semantic-ui so I decided to create an responsive application just to get a better understanding of semantic-ui's 16 grid architecture. I've added a [vertical menu](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html) in a column (three wide column). At a wide of 870px the vertical menu breaks the layout by underlapping a thirteen wide column on the same row.

I have noticed that semantic ui supplies various sizes for the vertical menu I'm working with however there isn't an example showing how to create a responsive menu, so I am using JavaScript to listen for the change of the browser's width to hide the menu at 870px or less.

When I manually refresh the browser at 870px the menu hides, however when i resize the browser to 870px the menu does not hide (unless i refresh the page). When resizing the browser to 870px or less i would like the menu to hide. Also, is there away to resize the menu to the various sizes provided by semantic-ui so that I do not need to use JavaScript in this way?

**JS code used to hide menu**:

```
 //menu width
    function winPos() {
        var menu = document.querySelector('#test');
        var win = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 870px)');

        if (win.matches) {
            menu.classList.add('hide');
            console.log('goodbye')
        } else{
            menu.classList.remove('hide');
        }
    }
    winPos()
```

**HTML Snippet:**

```
<div class="three wide column">

            <div id="test" class="ui medium vertical menu">
                <a class="active item">
                    <div class="ui teal label">1</div>
                    Inbox
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <div class="ui label">51</div>
                    Spam
                </a>
                <a class="item">
                    <div class="ui label">1</div>
                    Updates
                </a>
                <div class="ui search">
                    <div class="ui icon input">
                        <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="friend search...">
                        <i class="search icon"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="results">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- three -->

        <div class="thirteen wide column">
            <div class="ui special cards"> ...
```

**CSS:**

```
.hide{
display: none!important;
}
```